# How to solve ng build library Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6

Aftyer command `ng build lib` I  got this error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'tsickle/src/tsickle'
```

I have tried to install `npm i tsickle` no effect.

```
"@angular/core": "^6.0.0"
```

Ts is:

```
  "typescript": "~2.7.2"
```

This `node_modules\ng-packagr\lib\ngc\create-emit-callback.js` module required the `tsicckle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should install tsickle as dev dependency

```
npm i --save-dev tsickle
```

Comment: I have tried, does not work

Comment: I got the same error after install

Comment: @Beginner what tsickle Version do you use ? can you post your package.json, please.